# Add custom column during Eloquent search

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

My model currently has title and original_title fields, I want to make a search and unify both columns in one the value of that column should be the value of title, but if title is empty I use the value of original_title instead.

I know I can do something like this

```php
$db = $this->db;

       $activity = Activity::addSelect(
                $db::raw('(CASE WHEN title = "" THEN original_title ELSE title) as coolTitle')
            );
```

but Im not a fan of using raw queries, so I was wondering is there is a "cleaner" way to do it.

Comment: There's no Laravel built-in method for `CASE` raw query. But, you can use global or local scope.

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more information. When you say empty, do you mean empty string or null value ?

Also will original_title be null/empty when title is set ? If so, try this :

```
$activity = Activity::whereNotNull('title',$search)->orWhere('original_title',$search)->get();
```

Comment: I mean empty string, 

The problem with that approach is that it will filter the results depending if title is null or original_title is the $search value

I want to bring all the results, but adding a new column to the resulting collection were the value will be title or if title is an empty string will be original_title 

I need  it specifically to later sort the results using that column

Comment: Maybe you can assign the value to a new column in your app layer. Use something like      $activity->title ? $activity->title : $activity->original_title